# Emulator or Real device which one result is trustable?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Running my app on emulator nexus API level 19 ARM(armeabi-v7a) giving me out of memory or bad allocation errors but when I'm running the same app on Annova cell phone and prestigeo multipad its working fine without any error. 
should I consider the emulator result and solve the errors or I can go with the real device results? 
I'm using picasso for images and emulator given error for them.
Any suggestion please..

Comment: Provide Emulator configuration

Comment: nexus API level 19 ARM(armeabi-v7a) Nexus 5(4.95", 1080x1920:xxhdpi)

Comment: Real device is more trustable.

Comment: memory errors that occur in Emulator might be due to the memory allocated for the emulator when you created it. Real device test results are more reliable. You might also want test it on other emulators like Genymotion to make sure that error is because of how you configured the emulator

Comment: I tested my app also on bluestakes app player, its working fine.As i read about picasso it handle the OOM problem then why after using picasso i'm facing the OOM in emulator?